# How to work with jQuery selectors over document.body.innerHTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have document.body.innerHTML as string (returned from function- other html document).

Can i work with it with jQuery and selectors? Just dont want to make something like this:

```
var bodyBefore = document.body.innerHTML;
$(document.body).html(response.dom); // returned document.body.innerHTML from other HTML page
// work ...
$(document.body).html(bodyBefore);
```

Need other way...

Answer (score 3):

yes you would do something like this:

```
$('selector-inside-dom', response.dom).action();
```

for example:

```
var externalDoc = response.dom;
var body = $('body', externalDoc).html();
```